# Ubuntu 12.10 indicator-sound shows as mute (three hyphens

Tags: 12.10, sound, mute, gateway

I kind of have a problem. 
I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and my sound seems to be fine. I can play videos etc. The trouble I have is the indicator-sound applet shows as a speaker with three hyphens as if it is in mute. The slider to turn the volume up/down looks like how you would expect it to be if it was muted. But I have sound.

I want to fix this so I can use that slider for what it is meant for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know the exact details of my sounds card. All I could tell you at this moment is it is onboard sound on a Gateway DX4860 (tower).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you add a screen-shoot? You can upload it in [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) and link it into your question.

Comment: Thanks Lucio, I found the problem this morning, it has to do with me moving my home to a second HDD formatted as NTFS. Ubuntu changed ownership of that to root and will not let me change it to me (gksudo nautilus or sudo chown -R paul /home/paul

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm glade that you find the solution. Please, **create a new answer to tell us how did you resolved the problem**. That is how the site work. Is more useful than show it into a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Answer created by @[maramyfriend](https://askubuntu.com/users/144910/maramyfriend) in a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274265/ubuntu-12-10-indicator-sound-shows-as-mute-three-hyphens#comment344517_274265):*

> Thanks Lucio, I found the problem this morning, it has to do with me moving my home to a second HDD formatted as NTFS. Ubuntu changed ownership of that to root and will not let me change it to me (gksudo nautilus or sudo chown -R paul /home/paul